# How to determine average mortgage balance for two part-year mortgages

Tags: united-states, income-tax, mortgage, tax-deduction

In US federal income taxes, the mortgage interest itemized deduction is reduced if the mortgage debt exceeds $1,000,000 (for loans taken out after 1987) or $750,000 (for loans taken out after 2017). In [Publication 936](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p936), it seems that this is "average balance" of all the home acquisition debt.

However, after reading the publication, I am still not clear on how this average is considered when a mortgage starts or ends in the middle of the year. Consider the example of a person who buys a new house and sells an old house during the year, with the following two mortgages, both of which were taken out after 2017 (the numbers are made up):

```
Mortgage A balance:
Jan: $200k
Feb: $199k
Mar: $198k
Apr: $197k
May: $196k
Jun: $195k
Jul: $194k
Aug: $193k
Sep: $192k
Oct: $191k
Nov: $190k
house is sold at the end of Nov

Mortgage B balance:
house is purchased at the beginning of Sep
Sep: $800k
Oct: $798k
Nov: $796k
Dec: $794k
```

What should be the average mortgage balance here? I can think of two options:

1. Add up all the monthly balances for all mortgages, and then divide by 12. This effectively takes the average balance of each mortgage over the whole year, including the months when the mortgage did not exist and the house was not owned. This comes out to $5.138 million / 12 = about $428k, which is well below the $750k limit, which means all the mortgage interest for the year is deductible.
2. Take the average balance of each mortgage only over the part of the year that that mortgage existed and the house was owned, and then add them up. This would result in the average for mortgage A being $195k, and for mortgage B being $797k, for a total of $992k, which is above the $750k limit, which means only a portion of the mortgage interest for the year is deductible.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 2):

Read [the pub](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p936#en_US_2021_publink1000230028) carefully:

> You have to figure the average balance **of each mortgage** to determine your qualified loan limit

You have two mortgages. Follow the worksheet:

> 1. Enter the balance as of the first day of the year that the mortgage was secured by your qualified home during the year (generally, January 1)   _____
> 2. Enter the balance as of the last day of the year that the mortgage was secured by your qualified home during the year (generally, December 31)  _____
> 3. Add amounts on lines 1 and 2    _____
> 4. Divide the amount on line 3 by 2.0. Enter the result

Mortgage 1: Jan-November, so you sum up the balances in January and November and divide by 2 to get the average.

Mortgage 2: Sep-Dec, similarly sum up the balances in September and December, divide by 2 to get the average.

That would be your option #2, which leads to only a portion of the interest being deductible. That's the intuitively expected results since you have the new mortgage over 750K, so it shouldn't be fully deductible.

You then need to carefully follow the steps for Table 1, and put the appropriate amounts in the appropriate lines on the table for the math to work.

Comment: But let's say the two mortgages didn't overlap, and the first had a balance of $500k, sold the house on Jun 30 and bought a new house on Jul 1 with mortgage balance of also $500k. According to this method, wouldn't this have $1 million average balance and also not fully deductible? If so, this would seem surprising.

Comment: @user102008 no, how? You average each separately.

Comment: Because in that case, at no point did you have more than $500k in mortgage balance. If it were the same house, and you just refinanced it, it would qualify for full deduction. Why should it be different just because you exchanged the house for an identical house with identical mortgage balance?

Comment: it shouldn't. I don't see who it would using this spreadsheet. "no, how?" was in response to your "*According to this method...*" claim.

Comment: @user102008 I see why the confusion. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I think "borrow any new amounts on the mortgage" refers to a cash-out refinance, which obviously cannot use the first and last method, since not all of the balance is used for acquisition of the house. I don't think the interest/rate method is applicable since it says, "You can use this method if at all times in 2021 the mortgage was secured by your qualified home", and that wouldn't be true for a house that was bought or sold during the year.

Comment: @user102008 did you follow the steps for table 1? You can use all three methods, and it should all end up more or less the same if you follow the table properly.